# How to send email with Mailgun to Gmail with content

Tags: ruby, smtp, gmail, mailgun

I'm using Mailgun to send email through SMTP.

It is working perfectly except that if I send two email with different content, Gmail stacks then in a list and the second one has no content. I don't understand why.  In my Mailgun log it shows it was sent with content.

Should I change the subject?

[image]

Comment: If you click on the `...` dots it will show you the content. I google stack email with same from name/email, subject line  and almost similar content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an issue related to Gmail's presentation of email.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". You're asking us to diagnose a problem with no idea what code you're using.